# Yii2: How to select last second (penultimate) record in the table?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

How to select last second record (that goes before the last one) from the table?
Next statement works OK, but selects the last record:

```
SystemStatisticsHistory::find()->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])->one();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `OFFSET` clause:

```
SystemStatisticsHistory::find()->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])->offset(1)->one();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#offset()-detail

Comment: No problem. But upvoting/accepting answers is a better thanks than writing "thanks" in a comment. :)

Comment: yea, sure, but I've just registered here so my votes doesn't counts :( "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: I see ... Well, I'm pretty sure you start with 101 reputation, so you've probably posted a bunch of low-quality questions/answers and got down-voted. You'll have to work your way back up, I guess.

Comment: ... apparently not. Didn't know you start with 1 rep now. :)